# subplot2grid with seaborn overwrites same ax

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

What is the correct way of specifying the ax where I want a chart to go?

Currently I'm trying to plot different heatmaps, each one in a different ax. But  when trying this it just plots the 2 charts one on top of the other.

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

ax1     = plt.subplot2grid((11,2),(0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)
ax2     = plt.subplot2grid((11,2),(4,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)

ax1 = sns.heatmap(dict_pivots['df_pivot_10_win_2_thres'], square=False, cmap="RdYlBu", 
                    linewidths=0.1, annot=True, annot_kws={"size":12})

ax2 = sns.heatmap(dict_pivots['df_pivot_5_win_2_thres'], square=False, cmap="RdYlBu", 
                    linewidths=0.1, annot=True, annot_kws={"size":12})
```

and this is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: You need to tell heatmap what `ax` to plot onto.

Comment: Pls publish full code so this can be tested. Suggestion is to use twinx:  ax2 = ax1.twinx()  Then draw the data on ax2 and show the plot.

Comment: @mwaskom I thought I was doing that specifying ax1 and ax2? Or it needs to be done "inside" heatmap?

Comment: Those are just names for return values. You need to pass them as arguments to the function...

Comment: @mwaskom I'm trying to learn how to do it, but https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/ says  "Access forbidden" . Any other place I can look into? Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel https://seaborn.github.io/ , but it's just `sns.heatmap(..., ax=ax1)`

Comment: @PaulH want to write as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass your Axes objects to the `heatmap` function:

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig3 = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((11,2),(0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((11,2),(4,0), rowspan=3, colspan=1)

ax1 = sns.heatmap(dict_pivots['df_pivot_10_win_2_thres'],
                  square=False,  cmap="RdYlBu",
                  linewidths=0.1, annot=True,
                  annot_kws={"size":12},
                  ax=ax1)  # <-- here

ax2 = sns.heatmap(dict_pivots['df_pivot_5_win_2_thres'],
                  square=False,  cmap="RdYlBu",
                  linewidths=0.1, annot=True,
                  annot_kws={"size":12},
                  ax=ax2)  # <-- and here
```